# running multiple flask webservice on single port

Tags: python, linux, web-services, flask

I need to run multiple flask webservice on single port.

I am able to run only one webservice on port 8080 using:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080,debug=True)
```

How can i run more than one webservice using this port as i have the luxury of using only this port.

Comment: Usually a web server like apache or nginx runs on port 8080, and the requests are passed from the web server to the flask applications. [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html)

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need "multiple flask services"? Seems like you just want one, which includes multiple endpoints.

Comment: Maybe [DispatcherMiddleware](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appdispatch/) will help you...

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Thanks. This is what i needed